# Using Google Spreadsheet API without having values in header row in lower case with spaces removed

Tags: google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I was wondering if there is any way around (read: hacks) using the Google Spreadsheet API that doesn't impose the restriction of having the values in the header row in lowercase with no spaces.
I'm aware that I can just make use of the cell based feed but that would have an overhead of my application having to track what column number corresponds to a particular column name.

Does anyone have an alternative means?

(Also I noticed that the [Google Spreadsheet API Docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) doesn't make any mention of the header row name restriction, I had to search around to find out why my code wasn't working initially)

Comment: Is the api not simply transforming the header values to single word lowercase? So if you have "My Header" in your spreadsheet you access it as "myheader" through the api, i.e. you can have values without this restriction in your spreadsheet and still access it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to actually change any headers in your spreadsheet and bent to some restrictions. Basically the API transforms your headers into the "lowercase no-space" format and you can access them as such. So trying to access a column with a header "My Header" would work by querying the column "myheader". The headers in the original spreadsheet remain unchanged and in the desired format.

Answer (score 2):

```
#header_names = list of header names
spreadclient = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient(source='Your App Name')

#Add a line to authenticate the spreadsheet client

spreadsheet_key = spreadsheet.GetId().split("%3A")[1]
worksheets = spreadclient.GetWorksheets(spreadsheet_key)
#get worksheet id
wsid =  worksheets.entry[0].GetWorksheetId()
#header row can only be accessed via cellfeed
for i,name in enumerate(header_names):
    cellentry= spreadclient.GetCell(spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id=wsid, row_num=1, col_num=1+i)
    #update value
    cellentry.cell.input_value = name #TODO: do batch update instead
    spreadclient.update(cellentry)
```

Comment: @fordpw This works for python. You'd need the gdata client library